# How to get a sublist of an ArrayDeQue?

Tags: java, list, arraydeque

I want to get sublist of an [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) such [there is in ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)). Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Do you need it to be backed by the original Deque?  In other words, do you need changes to the “sublist” to be immediately reflected in the original Deque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest route would be to create a new `ArrayList` from the `Deque` and `sublist` that.

```
public void test() {
    ArrayDeque<String> ad = new ArrayDeque<>();
    ad.add("Hello");
    ad.add("Bye!");
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>(ad);
    List<String> alp = al.subList(1, al.size());
    System.out.println("ad=" + ad);
    System.out.println("al=" + al);
    System.out.println("alp=" + alp);
}
```

Note, however, that the `ArrayList` is a **copy** of the state of the `Deque` at the time and does not reflect changes in the `Deque`. If that is unacceptable then there are otrher (less simple) options.